# Morse code is a ternary human-optimised code, is there a binary, non-machine optimised code?

Tags: technology, language

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34067/is-morse-code-without-spaces-uniquely-decipherable

Discusses how Morse code isn't very clear without the third (usually) unseen element, the space.

Is there a (historical?) human-optimised (vs. say, ascii or something) binary (on vs. off) code for transmitting information?

---

After sleeping on it, I recall one code used by Vietnam-era POWs, based on a 5x5 grid reference, optimised for decoding/learning (alphabetical order) vs. optimised for use.  But, I'm not sure that it didn't also use spaces.

Comment: This is not a history question by any length, as it stands now.

Comment: Why not?  What type of question *is* it?

Comment: Computer science experts might know what you are talking about. Your requirement is for a particular type of code. The specifications make it the subject of computer science experts or mathematicians. Whether it existed in the past is immaterial. Else people can ask calculus questions here because after all it was invented in the past.

Comment: Uhh, Morse code is computer science? o_O  I'm asking about a historical (in-use) language equivalent.  There's a difference between asking what something (calculus) is called, or if it exists - than asking how to solve a particular problem using calculus.

Comment: The problem is your definition comes through a specification- not a readily understood term outside specialized circles. I could ask if a DCT based algorithm existed before 1995. That does not make it a history question.

Comment: Questions on scholarly disciplines other than History are off-topic here, unless they also involve history in some fashion.  Referencing "the past" is not history.

Comment: There's the smoke signal that the Vatican Council uses to communicate when they are voting. Black smoke means they haven't elected a new Pope yet, and white smoke means they have. I'd imagine a lot of other smoke signal systems can be thought of a binary communications as well, as the medium has many similarities to telegraph.

Comment: @Rajib, you are completely wrong: binary codes, including Morse, Braille, and visual telegraphs (as opposed to electric ones) were developed long time before computers and computer science. Just because OP mentioned something from computer science to clarify that *HE DOES NOT WANT COMPUTER RELATED ANSWERS* doesn't mean that the question is computer related.

Comment: BTW, Morse code is actually binary: it consists of on/off signals over time intervals. Dot is defined as ON over 1 times interval followed by OFF over 1 time interval, dash is defined as ON over 3 time interval followed by OFF over 1 time interval, and inter-word space is defined as OFF over 3 time interval.

Comment: @Michael Is binary code questions fair game for history forum? Not unless explained clearly in terms that non-mathematicians and non-computer-science people can understand. My point is questions that require specialized knowledge outside history should be asked elsewhere where there are qualified persons.

Comment: @Rajib, I am speechless. "Binary code" is a synonym for "an alphabet with exactly two symbols"; there is no need for specialized knowledge to understand the concept. Putting on hold a question about the *history* of human-readable binary code because the question use the words "binary code" is the same as putting on hold a question about history of internal combustion engines because it used specialized term "internal combustion" or putting on hold a question about history of impressionism because it used the specialized term "impressionism".

Comment: @Michael Read the post's last para. Maybe I'm daft/dumb, but please- if this is explained in English, I will vote to reopen. Maybe the "synonym" should have been explained better for people who don't specialize in semiotics/linguistics or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille , in its various language formats, is a binary human-optimised code. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_writing , Braille's precursor, also fits your description request. 
Both codes are fixed-length, and therefore do not suffer from the problem as quoted in the question.

Comment: Not to mention various smoke and visual signals used over centuries.